# How can set which data in this Entity will be save to the DB (Mysql)

Tags: orm, one-to-one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "verification_token")
public class VerificationTokenEntity {
    private static final int EXPIRATION = 60 * 24;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="token")
    private String token;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = BillEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bill_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private BillEntity billEntity;

    @Column(name="created_date")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name="expiry_date")
    private Date expiryDate;
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "bill", schema = "bigproject")
public class BillEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "info")
    private String info;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "status_id")
    private Long statusId;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "room_id")
    private Long roomId;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvhgK.png)
When i save this verificationEntity into the Database, it always save the room_id from the billEntity to the bill_id field. How can set which attribute will be save to the Database?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrfui.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy5uB.png)

How can set which attribute will be save to the Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/booking/{id}")
public String showFormBooking(@PathVariable Long id , Model model){
    BillDto billDto = new BillDto();
    model.addAttribute("id",id);
    model.addAttribute("billDto",billDto);
    RoomDto roomDto = roomService.getDetailById(id);
    model.addAttribute("roomDto",roomDto);
    ResortDto resortDto = resortService.getDetailById(roomDto.getResortId());
    model.addAttribute("resortDto",resortDto);
    ResortImageDto resortImageDto = resortImageService.getFirstByResortId(roomDto.getResortId());
    model.addAttribute("resortImageDto",resortImageDto);
    return "frontend/booking.html";
}
```

I figure out that bill_id field got the wrong value is not because it come from the room_id from BillEntity

Turn out it come from the id of BillEntity itself. Before, the id of the BillEntity always null before it's saved into the DB, the way i code, then it will get a id automatically with the auto_increment.

```
 <form th:action="@{/booking/} + ${roomDto.id}"
       th:object="${billDto}" th:method="post">
```

But this time, when the billDto is posted, it take @PathVariable Long id (this is supposed to be room_id) as billDto ('id')

So to fix this, i simply change all the pathvariable name from id -> roomid

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/booking/{roomid}")
public String showFormBooking(@PathVariable Long roomid , Model model){
    BillDto billDto = new BillDto();
    model.addAttribute("roomid",roomid);
    model.addAttribute("billDto",billDto);
    RoomDto roomDto = roomService.getDetailById(roomid);
    model.addAttribute("roomDto",roomDto);
    ResortDto resortDto = resortService.getDetailById(roomDto.getResortId());
    model.addAttribute("resortDto",resortDto);
    ResortImageDto resortImageDto = resortImageService.getFirstByResortId(roomDto.getResortId());
    model.addAttribute("resortImageDto",resortImageDto);
    return "frontend/booking.html";
}
```